# Hibernate Search Index Automatically when changes happens to database

Tags: hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I know that Hibernate Search will do reindex when we update data through hibernate. But what if I want it to index when database has changes (without going through hibernate). What configuration should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either index specific entities (if you happen to "know" their ids) or have Hibernate Search re-build entire indexes using its mass indexer.

Check out [chapter 6](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#manual-index-changes) of the Hibernate Search reference guide ("Manual index changes") to learn how it's done.